# How do I pass a variant array element to ChrW() in VBA?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, variant

I am trying to pass a variant array element (contains a long value) to the ChrW() function, which takes a Long type argument (character code), but the ChrW() function is returning "?".

I have tried creating long variables, assigning the array element to the long variable and passing this to ChrW(), but I get the same result.

```
Sub test()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim m As Long
    Dim n As Long

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Emojis")
    Dim a As Variant
    ' Load the values from the sheet into the array
    a = ws.Range("A1:B65").Value

    For i = 1 To 5
        m = a(i, 1)
        n = a(i, 2)
        Debug.Print m; n; ChrW(m) & ChrW(n)
    Next I    
End Sub
```

The sheet from which the array is loaded contains these cell values (Type is Number) values:
-10179  -9148

-10179  -9140

-10179  -9139

-10179  -9137

etc.

The Debug.Print output:

-10179 -9148 ??

-10179 -9140 ??

-10179 -9139 ??

-10179 -9137 ??

etc.

Comment: m = CLng( a(i, 1))

Comment: Do not use Immediate window for unicode chars  output. Just assign the value to a cell.

Comment: @HarassedDad, thank you, but this had the same result.

Comment: @omegastripes, thank you, this helped me solve my issue.  I had incorrectly assumed that the ChrW() was literally returning "?".  The code I posted actually works and produces the results I needed.